# although the bare python flask start successfully, my uwsgi started failed with strange python library import error

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I developed one webserver with python flask framework hosted with uwsgi. It works well on one computer, and when I ported it onto another computer with the exactly same configurations, i.e, Ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7, uwsgi 2.0, but the uwsgi failed with strange import error.

I can start my web service successfully with bare python command line as

```
python HelloCityEye.py
```

Everthing shows right as the service is started.

```
    # python HelloCityEye.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
2019-09-12 16:09:27,129 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-09-12 16:09:27,129 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-09-12 16:09:27,130 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-09-12 16:09:27,130 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-09-12 16:09:27,131 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("users")
2019-09-12 16:09:27,131 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 * Serving Flask app "HelloCityEye" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
2019-09-12 16:09:27,690 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-09-12 16:09:27,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-09-12 16:09:27,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-09-12 16:09:27,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-09-12 16:09:27,692 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("users")
2019-09-12 16:09:27,692 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 102-535-023
```

I can access my web service with any web-browser.

Then I would like to host the flask web service with uwsgi framework as following configuration as temp.ini file (the same as previous working computer)

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye
virtualenv = /home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye
module=HelloCityEye
callable=app

master=true
processes=20

http = 127.0.0.1:9090
```

However, when I try to start the uwsgi with following command

```
# ./bin/uwsgi temp.ini
```

The error message jumps into a python issue

```
(cityeye) root@ubuntu:/home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye# ./bin/uwsgi temp.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from temp.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Thu Sep 12 16:44:06 2019] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 02 May 2016 17:58:33
os: Linux-4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018
nodename: ubuntu
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye
detected binary path: /home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
chdir() to /home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye
your processes number limit is 1903
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on 127.0.0.1:9090 fd 4
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:45929 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)  [GCC 7.3.0]
Set PythonHome to /home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x11b0f90
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 1527960 bytes (1492 KB) for 20 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./HelloCityEye.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Earth2Mars  # coordinate transformation
  File "./Earth2Mars.py", line 12, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .mtrand import *
ImportError: /home/gongming/pythonwork/cityeye/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 10716)
...
spawned uWSGI worker 20 (pid: 10737, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 10738)
```

Even I reinstall the numpy package, it doesn't help.

I am sure it should not be the python library ImportError, since not only I can run it with directly with python without uwsgi hosted, but also I can use uwsgi without any issue on another ubuntu computer.

Then, what caused the errors?

Thanks for attensions.

Comment: maybe multiprocessing (`processes=20`) causes this problem. uwsgi creates an app object and forks it. this can cause database connections to fail etc. try adding `lazy-app=true` to your uwsgi config and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried your method, adding ```lazy-app=true```, reducing or even removing the ```processes```, however the same error as before.